# Obtain Frame rectangle size from storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a view in my storyboard that I use multiple times to construct a single view for a popover.  I want to obtain the view's frame rectangle before I load the first instance so I can calculate the overall size/positioning information for the popover. Is it possible to retrieve the frame info from the storyboard without instantiating the VC/View from the storyboard?

Comment: Generally with custom views (both in OSX and iOS) you don't really care the size of the container it is being displayed within.  Why not simply create a custom view subclass and override the `setFrame:` method?

Comment: I could, but why not use the information in the storyboard?  Am I missing something?

Comment: maybe i am wrong but if this is regarding different screen sizes then maybe (_just maybe_) you're over-thinking things. Well... the sizes defined in the storyboard or xib are static (_right?_). Copy that and apply AutoSizing masks / AutoLayout constraints on it. Whenever you access the frame, you **will** get the same frame  size anyways.